# Write two R output data in a same excel spreadsheet

Tags: r, excel, output, export-to-excel

I am a beginner in R and I would like to write output data composed of two matrices with column and row names from each one in a same excel spreadsheet. 
I tried to concatenate the two matrices that have the same dimension but I failed.

```
First case   Conversion time      Value   Parameter Conversion prob
Mean   1.111583       0.9690824 0.9922606664  0.80429352          0.9017
Std    1.111583       1.7619508 0.0004687991  0.01161018          0.9017
Min    1.111583       0.0060000 0.9891755625  0.72675179          0.9017
Max    1.111583       9.2480000 0.9935047362  0.81800510          0.9017

Second case   Conversion time      Value   Parameter Conversion prob
Mean   1.113336        2.201757 0.9867097947  0.55481942          0.7674
Std    1.113336        2.394181 0.0003237515  0.01084467          0.7674
Min    1.113336        0.050000 0.9844458277  0.47898355          0.7674
Max    1.113336        9.244000 0.9870852487  0.56739596          0.7674
```

Could someone please give me a hand with that ?

> **Edit:** I can't install XLConnect. Actually I'm not allowed to install any
>   package in the computer in which I am working. Does anyone know an
>   alternative method to the one proposed by @nrussell producing the same output ?

Comment: Can you please add your R code and a sample of your data?

Comment: @nrussell: I added the data as you suggested. Could you take a look please?

Comment: You could either concatenate your matrix (using either `rbind` or `cbind`) or use the `append` option in `write.table` function. I usually avoid installing packages when the basic R packages do the trick. `write.table` exports your data in `.csv`, which you can open with MS Excel and save it as a spreadsheet.

Comment: @Bernardo I generally use base R functions like `write.csv` when writing data to spreadsheets, but my interpretation was that the OP wanted to include the column names from both of his objects, and I got error messages when trying to append the file (presumably from trying to include column names from the second object).

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly clear on what you are looking for, but how about something like this, which uses the package `XLConnect`:

```
library(XLConnect)
##
## Some toy data
M1 <- matrix(
  data=cbind(
    rep(1.111583,4),
    rnorm(4),
    rnorm(4),
    rnorm(4),
    prob=rep(0.9017,4)),
  nrow=4)
##
colnames(M1) <- c(
  "First Case","Conversion Time",
  "Value","Parameter Conversion","Prob")
rownames(M1) <- c(
  "Mean","Std","Min","Max")
##
M2 <- M1
M2[,5] <- rep(0.7674,4)
colnames(M2)[1] <- "Second Case"
##
> head(M1)
     First Case Conversion Time       Value Parameter Conversion   Prob
Mean   1.111583       0.5137628  0.50627262            1.6387446 0.9017
Std    1.111583       0.3992718  0.34755198           -0.8755925 0.9017
Min    1.111583       1.6628564 -0.37723765            0.1217600 0.9017
Max    1.111583       0.2758934  0.09761946            1.3621307 0.9017
> head(M2)
     Second Case Conversion Time       Value Parameter Conversion   Prob
Mean    1.111583       0.5137628  0.50627262            1.6387446 0.7674
Std     1.111583       0.3992718  0.34755198           -0.8755925 0.7674
Min     1.111583       1.6628564 -0.37723765            0.1217600 0.7674
Max     1.111583       0.2758934  0.09761946            1.3621307 0.7674
##
```

**Edit:** My last example didn't include row names -

```
D1 <- data.frame(
  cbind(
    "Row.Name"=rownames(M1),
    M1))
##
D2 <- data.frame(
  cbind(
    "Row.Name"=rownames(M2),
    M2))
##
Wb <- loadWorkbook(
  "matrixes.xlsx",
  create=TRUE)
createSheet(
  Wb,"newSheet")
##
writeWorksheet(
  object=Wb,
  data=D1,
  rownames=NULL,
  header=TRUE,
  sheet="newSheet")
##
appendWorksheet(
  object=Wb,
  data=D2,
  rownames=NULL,
  sheet="newSheet",
  header=TRUE)
##
saveWorkbook(Wb,file="matrices.xlsx")
```

Which gives you this:
[image]

This required a bit more work than typically writing multiple objects to a spreadsheet because I assumed you wanted to include the column names from each matrix. Trying to do this with `write.table`, you get this:

```
## Initial write works:
write.table(
  M1,file="matrices.csv",
  row.names=T,
  col.names=T)
## append=TRUE gives warning when col.names=TRUE
## and file is malformed
write.table(
  M2,file="matrices.csv",
  append=TRUE,
  row.names=T,
  col.names=T)
Warning message:
In write.table(M2, file = "matrices.csv", append = TRUE, row.names = T,  :
  appending column names to file
```

[image]

So the `XLConnect` approach requires a little more effort than usual, but it offers a lot more functionality than `write.csv` and `write.table`, like custom cell formatting, etc...

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. What about importing inputs from excel and then export the outputs to the same spreadsheets ? I'm now improoving my solution to read some parameter from excel and give the output (the same format then in this question). Could you give me a hint ? I have no idea for the moment how to do it in the same spreadsheet. (a feature similar to the one we could produce with C++ and VBA)

Comment: I cant install **XLConnect**. Actually I'm not allowed to install any package in the computer in which I am working. Do you Know any alternative to produce the same output ?

Comment: So you unaccepted the answer? There's probably a way to do this without XLConnect.

Comment: I just unaccepted your answer for the moment because otherwise other persons would probably be less motivated to answer. I should maybe split it in another question but I will let like this for the moment. I hope you understand.